# "Parseltongue": get Ruby to Speak a bit of Python?

Tags: python, ruby, multilingual

Just for interest really - community wiki - how much Python can we get Ruby to understand ?
[ Probably be just as interesting to do the reverse as well].

The experiment (such as it is) perhaps to see how much can be written in Ruby-Cross-Python scripts that will result in identical outputs. The only 'cheat' I guess being allowed here is the too allow Ruby statements to precede the eventual 'common' script. [like the 'len' definition below].

For instance, this works in both:

```
a=[1,2,3]
mystring="hello"
bobby="hello"*3
epoch=1270123200
map={}
map['supamu']='egusu'
map['dedu']='paroto'

keys=map.keys()
values=map.values()
```

And doing this in Ruby:

```
class Object
    def len(object)
        object.size
    end
end

class Object
    def str(object)
        object.to_s
    end
end
```

Means this now works in both:

```
a=[1,2,3]
mystring="hello"
len(a)
len(mystring)
str(123)
```

I think the trouble will come with conditionals and loops, due to different syntax requirements. (the ':' at the end of Python lines for instance...)

Comment: so, **make** it community wiki!

Comment: I assume you're kidding.  It's not April 1st, so perhaps you're not.  What exactly are you asking?  Are there syntax overlaps between Ruby and Python?  Why limit it to Ruby and Python?  Why not ask for a set of C preprocessor macros that allow the C compiler to translate Python?

Comment: Not sure why you are appear so upset about this...

Thought it might make a nice Wiki for people who know a bit of one language , to see how the other does it; and yes, to see how much syntax-overlap there is - it seems to be an interesting thing to do in its own right.

Personally - I'm just starting out with Python -  but I have some Ruby background - thought it might make for a good fun learning exercise.

Comment: Although the question is quite broad, I think its fine, mainly for such similar "rivals" like python and ruby. Every part of the languages maybe could be considered in a separate question, loops, conditionals, blocks,...

Comment: Syntax overlaps in programming languages seems like writing down a list of absurd coincidences.   It smacks of numerology or astrology or some other such "wrong order out of chaos" non-science.  I don't get the point.  It's cute, but what does it matter?  Why not look for Russian words in Cryllic that -- when held in a mirror -- look like English words in Latin?  That seems equally useful.

Comment: In one respect sir, your last comment resembles a well-written Test-Suite: it contains lots and lots of assertions. :-p

Answer (score 1):

To answer the question fully would probably need a bit of analysis. The control structures in both languages are defined to make our lives easier and the codes more readable when we program, but they could be realised with methods like it was in smalltalk. Iterations and conditionals (except the "case" statement) similarly as it was described in this blog: [Emulating Smalltalk’s Conditionals in Ruby](http://yehudakatz.com/2009/10/04/emulating-smalltalks-conditionals-in-ruby/). For example an "if" would look something like this:

```
(an_object.nil?).
 if_true  { puts "true" }.
 if_false { puts "false" }
```

I would suggest to cope with the iteration and conditionals by creation of an extension of the objects in both languages, which define the control structures as methods. This way it would possible to write a code with control structures which run in both languages.

But there other things, which lays deeper in the language design, which would be harder to cope with. In python every instance variable is public, in ruby they are private. What are the differences in changing self..?

Maybe if we started to reduce and omit the syntactical things to method calls we would end up with a very simple syntax... with something similar to smalltalk.